# I have to concentric circles how do i limit the drag of inner circle within the outer circle +java

Tags: java

I have to concentric circles how  do i limit the drag of inner circle within the outer circle +java

Comment: please specify. which package are you using? is it just mathematical restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying a particular library...

- The distance of the centre of the inner circle from the centre of the outer circle

plus

- The radius of the inner circle

must not exceed

- The radius of the outer circle.

Comment: The common definition of concentric is common center.  So the distance of the center of the inner circle from the center of the outer circle is always zero.  Simplifying - inner circle radius must be less than outer circle radius.